# Custom str split vs strtok

Tags: c

The `strtok` function seems so odd to me, though I'm not sure if that's because I'm a beginner in C or if it actually is thought to be an oddity among experienced programmers. Here is what I'm currently doing to split a string:

```
char *str = "first,last,age\ntom,smith,20\nsarah,jones,30";
char row_buffer[80];
char c;
int str_i = 0, buf_i = 0;

do {
    c = str[str_i];

    if (c != '\n')
        row_buffer[buf_i++] = c;
    else {
        row_buffer[buf_i] = '\0';
        buf_i = 0;
        // process_function()
    }
} while (str[str_i++]);
```

Does this seem to be overkill for splitting a string in C, or is this similar to how it's done?

Comment: What in particular is wrong with `strtok()`?

Comment: @tadman passing `NULL` seems weird to me.

Comment: If I look at your code I have to trace it to see what it is doing. If it used `strtok` then I'd already have a pretty good idea. If you already know the wheel exists don't reinvent it unless you have a very good reason

Comment: It's a product of the time. It's a little state machine that needs to work efficiently. There's a multitude of things in C that are just plain bizarre, but have historical reasons for existing, even if that reason was "it seemed like a good idea at the time."

Comment: Most of the "normal" string parsing operations you may be comparing `strtok` to probably came 20-30 years later. C is 50 years old now, so it's a miracle that it's not _more_ bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposal is not overkill, it is actually a better approach to splitting a string than `strtok()` as it does not modify the source string.

Note however these remarks:

- you do not test if the string fragment fits in the temporary buffer.
- the semantics are slightly different from `strtok()`: consecutive separators produce empty fragments and an empty fragment is produced for an empty string. For example `"\n\n"` produces 3 fragments whereas `strtok()` produces none.